# Intel UHD Graphics 605 can't see screen to boot/install

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics

I have been attempting to install 18.04 on my new Lenovo D330.  It has a Intel UHD Graphics 605.

While I can get to grub (try ubuntu/install ubuntu) I cannot get beyond that unless I add nomodeset to the boot option.  If I don't do this, I get a black screen.

When I add nomodeset, I can get to the desktop, however it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMLSB.jpg

And when I try to swap to a tty after getting to the desktop, it is also unreadable:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP2sc.jpg

Is this card supported?  How do I go about updating the driver/kernel without seeing the screen?  I assume there's a way to turn off vid drivers so that the tty will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gfxpayload=800x1280 and nomodeset fixes this for the cheap version, ikhsan setiawan has a more expensive version that takes the 1200x1920 resolution.

Combo of Ikhsan and /u/133563 on reddit for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

it work fine for my d330 using ubuntu 18.04 and kernel 4.15, what kernel are you using?

as for the display error with nomodeset you can fix it by adding gfxpayload=1200x1920 to your grub

Comment: Did you need to do anything funky to get the install looking fine?  Were you using nomodeset etc?  I assume you did a straight install using 18.04 installer?  Unfortunately adding the gfxpayload option did not help.

I was installing using 18.04 default download, so that's kernel 4.15 for myself as well.

Comment: i didn't do anything & no nomodeset,just boot up the usb (yes the text was unreadable) but everything was fine after that.

Comment: btw, how do you add the gfxpayload option?

Comment: I edit grub line for starting distribution (I'm currently trying a mint distribution out of frustration, but it's the same result).  I have "set gfxpayload=1200x1920" above the linux line with quiet splash etc.  However this still results in a black screen unless I also use nomodeset (and then the resolution is still messed up)

Comment: Can you post your grub startup line?  I have forced an install of xubuntu 18.04.1 but still have these issues, same with recovery mode.

Comment: If it live cd just edit grub while booting and add gfxpayload=1200x1920 to the last line under initrd line.i'll post my grub.cfg later (doesn't have my device right now) or you can post yours so i can check if something wrong.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you managed to get screenrotation working with your set resolution?